# Ionic 3 - Update Observable with Asynchronous Data

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, ionic2, ionic3

For a social media app, I have a collection of feed objects referenced by their IDs using `AngularFire 2`. Once each of these IDs has its relevant data pulled from the database that stores the actual feed objects, I wish to update the `feedCards` Observable object with this information so I can asynchronously display a collection of feed objects in my HTML. It's a pretty confusing chain of events, so let me summarize it for you.

> Step-by-step Approach

1. `displayFeed()` is invoked right before the `NavController` loads the `feed` component on the `Main` page.
2. `displayFeed()` gets the `twiner` item, which is essentially a user profile item, and then stores the user profile in the `userProfile` variable.
3. Once the user profile is loaded, the global `feedCards` Observable is set equal to `loadFeed()`, which returns an Observable array.
4. `loadFeed()` uses the `id` value of the `userProfile` global object to load the list of feed references stored in the user profile.
5. This snapshot is then subscribed to and the local `feed` variable is set equal to the result list of feed references.
6. `loadFeed` returns an Observable object in which the `feed` reference list is mapped by the data each feed reference contains.
7. `pullFeedData(number)` takes in a reference to a feed object and returns an observable with the associated feed data.

> What Works

- `alert(JSON.stringify(feedData));` alerts the correct `feed` object
- Basically everything else.

> What Doesn't Work

- `feed.map(...` does not update the feed array because `pullFeedData(number)` pulls and returns the `feedData` asynchronously. Thus, `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` in `displayFeed()` alerts `[null]`.

> Code

`feed.ts`

```
   userProfile:any;
   feed: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
   feedData: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

   feedCards: Observable<any[]>;

   constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, public nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {}

   displayFeed():void {
        this.nativeStorage.getItem('twiner').then((res) => {
              this.userProfile = res;
              this.feedCards = this.loadFeed();
              this.feedCards.subscribe((data)=>{
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
              })
        });
  }

  loadFeed():Observable<any[]> {
        var feed;
        this.feed = this.db.list('/twiners/' + this.userProfile.id + '/feed', { preserveSnapshot: true });
        this.feed.subscribe((snapshots)=>{feed = snapshots});
        return Observable.of(feed.map((snapshot) => {
              this.pullFeedData(snapshot.val()).subscribe((feedData)=>{
                    alert(JSON.stringify(feedData));
                    return feedData;
              });
        })).delay(1000);
  }

  pullFeedData(twine:number):any {
        return this.db.object('/twines/' + twine, { preserveSnapshot: true });
  }
```

`feed.html`

```
<ion-content fullscreen scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true">
      <ion-card *ngIf="feedCards | async">feedCards exist</ion-card>
      <twine-feed-card *ngFor="let feedCard of feedCards | async"
            [data]="feedCard"
      ></twine-feed-card>
</ion-content>
```

> Summary

`feed.map` does not update `feed` with feed objects because the new data is being pulled asynchronously. I need a fix for this.

**Thank you!**

Comment: did you try running it inside zones..? (I used to use listobservables, now I use event emitters to achieve this real-time functionality)

Comment: @RajaYogan Do you mind reiterating how to use this functionality in zones? In short, I don't know what that is.

Comment: No probs.. do you get the data here in an alert..?
this.feedCards.subscribe((data)=>{
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
              })

Comment: @RajaYogan Nope, I don't. I put that in my original question.

Comment: I think you need to look at [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises).  They basically set up a callback function that gets called after the asynchronous behavior is complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subscribed observable does not return a value. It returns a `Subscription` object which you can use to unsubscribe later.

You can use `switchMap` to switch from first observable to the next during the call and return the values.
Also you can use `forkJoin` which will call an array of observables and wait till the array of values is returned in subscription.
First declare `feed` class variable as an `Observable`.

```
feed: Observable<any>;
```

Then in your `loadFeed():Observable<any[]>`

```
return this.feed.switchMap((snapshots) => {
             let observableArray = [];
             snapshots.forEach(snapshot =>{
                 observableArray.push(this.pullFeedData(snapshot.val()));
             });
             return Observable.forkJoin(observableArray)
        })
```

Comment: Finally got my code working with a forEach method following your answer. Thanks a bunch!! 