# Angular 4 - Loop Through Observables and Extract Values in New Array

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

> Background

I am currently making a find function for a messaging app, where each collection of messages is referenced by an index. When `find()` is invoked, it has to extract each message collection reference from the `messageRef` variable, then use `getMessageCollectionFromRef(id)` to get the Observable for the message collection. Then, it must grab the user `id` from this Observable's subscribed JSON data of the person who is *not* the user, and then invoke `getUserById(id)` to get the Observable for the user info. Lastly, it must compare the name of the retrieved user to the value of the `ngModel` `search`. If `search` is a substring of `userJSONData`, then the `messageRef` of the message collection must be put into the `messages` Observable, from which `async` data is loaded on the Angular front-end.

*Note: Function `cancelFind()` is called at the beginning of the `find()` function only to revert the message Observable list to its original length from AngularFire2 data. This works well.*

> Attempt

```
find():void {
        this.cancelFind();
        console.log("- find Started -");
        var newMessages = new Array();
        this.messages = this.messages.switchMap((messages) => {
              console.log("Got messages: " + JSON.stringify(messages));
              messages.forEach((msg) => {
                    console.log("Iterating through message #" + msg.$value);
                    this.msgClass.getMessageCollectionFromRef(msg.$value).take(1).subscribe((message) => {
                          var id = (message.messager1.id != this.user.id ? message.messager1.id : message.messager2.id)
                          this.userClass. getUserById(id).take(1).subscribe((messager) => {
                                if (messager.name.includes(this.search)) {
                                      console.log("Pushing " + JSON.stringify(msg) + " to list");
                                      newMessages.push(msg);
                                }
                          });
                    });
              });
              console.log("Found list: " + JSON.stringify(newMessages));
              return Observable.forkJoin(newMessages);
        });
        console.log("- find Resolved -");
  }
```

> Output

```
[08:41:59]  console.log: - find Started - 
[08:41:59]  console.log: Got messages: [{"$value":0},{"$value":1}] 
[08:41:59]  console.log: - find Resolved - 
[08:41:59]  console.log: Iterating through message #0
[08:41:59]  console.log: Iterating through message #1 
[08:41:59]  console.log: Found list: []
[08:41:59]  console.log: Pushing {"$value":0} to list
```

*Side note: Yes, I know my `- find Started -` and `- find Resolved -` logs follow synchronous conventions. This is standard in the app I'm developing and would not like to stray away from this.*

> Error

**I am not getting an error**, but my issue is that the `messages` Observable remains empty and, consequently, no message collections appear on screen.

This problem is very unique in that it concerns retrieving nested Observable values in a loop, and I have not found adequate solutions to this issue online. The only similar solutions, such as that to a question I asked months ago [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229741/ionic-3-update-observable-with-asynchronous-data), concern creating an Observable array off of synchronously-retrieved data.

I apologize for the adequately large description in relation to the length of code, but I believe there is an easy fix for this that I was not able to pinpoint for days. I am still new to Observables, so I will appreciate any help you can provide. ***Thank you so much!***

> CozyAzure's Solution

Following CozyAzure's solution, I have been able to produce a newly searched Observable array with properly added values. However, instead of omitting non-matches (`null` values), the `filter` command does not do anything to the result Observable array. Here is my resulting error:
[image: Error]

> Workaround

Check for null in your front-end as the `async` pipe loads messages.

```
<div *ngFor="let msg of messages | async">
      <message-card *ngIf="msg" [ref]="msg" ></message-card>
</div>
```

Comment: `getMessageCollectionFromRef()` can be called in parallel right?

Comment: Nope, you need the Message Collection to get the ID of the user whom you are messaging.

Comment: but, each subsequent calls has no dependency to each other right? You can fire them in parallel, and then compare the results later, no?

Comment: I agree with @CozyAzure, put a `console.log` before your return statement, you'll probably see that it is shown before **Pushing ... to list**

Comment: @CozyAzure Which calls do you mean? Calls to nested functions or each call to get a message collection?

Comment: @Nathan P. Good idea, I'll try this and update my question.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the advice! The result was pretty obvious, however, so my question stands as how it would be possible to return this array filled with values as an Observable array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I checked that question yesterday and it doesn't really help fix my issue. My problem concerns retrieving nested Observable values in a loop, and I have not found adequate solutions to this issue online.

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `forkJoin` _before_ `newMessages` is populated, and you'll find all the answers in the question I linked. Using promises will probably help you.

Comment: True, but my issue will then be determining when the newMessages scalar array is completely populated with message collection references so I can then use a callback to join the array into the messages Observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you got it mostly correct, other than changing some of the `subscribe` to `.switchMap` and `.map`.

I maybe understanding your requirement wrongly though. I am assuming you want an `Observable` that contains all the results after calling `this.msgClass.getMessageCollectionFromRef()`, and then just subscribed to it so that you get all the values.

Here's how you can do it:

```
find(): Observable<any> {
    return this.message
        .switchMap(messages => {
            let arrayOfObservables = messages.map(msg => {
                return this.msgClass.getMessageCollectionFromRef(msg.$value)
                    .take(1)
                    .switchMap(message => {
                        var id = (message.messager1.id != this.user.id ? message.messager1.id : message.messager2.id)
                        return this.userClass.getUserById(id)
                            .take(1)
                            .map(messager => {
                                return messager.name.includes(this.search) ? messager : null;
                            })
                    })
            });
            return Observable
                .forkJoin(...arrayOfObservables) 
                 //filter out the null values
                .filter(x => x !== null);
        })
}
```

Walkthrough:

1. Get all the messages from `this.messages`.
2. For each of these messages:

   2.1. call `msgClass.getMessageCollectionFromRef()`

   2.2. take the first value returned, and then

   - call `getUserById` with the id
   - map the `Observable`. If the response is the same as input, return the response, else return `Observable.empty`
3. Combine all the Observables in point 2 using `Observable.forkJoin()`
4. Filter out the values which are `null`

**Some notes:**

1. In your question, your method `.find()` explicitly stating return of `void`, but you are actually returning an `Observable`. You might want to fix that.
2. At step 3 and 4, Use rest parameters `...` to flatten the arrays to be passed into `.forkJoin` as arguments

Comment: Great idea, but switchMap would need a default value to return if a `messager` is not found. This is one of the issues I came across before. Is there a way to wait for the map to complete before returning a value in the switchMap method? Thank you!

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: @AnthonyKrivonos you are right. Just need to add the return statement. see my edit

Comment: Awesome! I'm almost there. Observable.empty() returns a `false` value for the `_isScalar` key, which is a tad hard to parse out of the Observable array. Do you know of a way to filter out null values in the returned Observable? I went on to change one of the last lines to `return twinee.name.includes(this.search) ? tw : null;` because it's easier to check for null.

Comment: @AnthonyKrivonos yes, simply use `Observable.filter()` . See my edit

Comment: For some reason, the Observable array still returns with null values. Check my edit!

Comment: Solved it in the front-end! Put my workaround in an edit.